# Need to capture every http sent/received from android app on device

Tags: android, http

Thats it. I want to capture every http request response sent to from an app running on android device.  I am offering a bounty for the answer to this question.  I don't think all features replay from emulator so I want to do this from the device itself.  Now I know there is wireshark on the PC, some apps for wireshark like shark reader gives back a lot of hex. My goal is to simulate offline a whole http request/response scenario from the app. This question has been asked in the past, but no clear answer on how it can be done for android successfully so I am offering a bounty.

Question with bounty is here:

[Android How To Simulate HTTP Communication for Offline Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233998/android-how-to-simulate-http-communication-for-offline-demo)

This one can be closed.

Comment: You might want to clarify whether or not your solution would allow a proxy that all HTTP requests could run through.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I accomplished it from my old HTC Droid Eris:

1. Install ProxyDroid on your phone https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en
2. Download and install charlesproxy on your computer http://www.charlesproxy.com/
3. Open Browser on your phone and navigate to http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt to install charlesproxy certificate
4. Open charlesproxy and go under Help -> Local IP Address to check your ip address
5. Open ProxyDroid on your phone enter your IP under host and 8888 under port and start ProxyDroid
6. Go back to charlesproxy and hit 'Start Recording' Now every request you make from your phone should be visible in charlesproxy

**IMPORTANT:** ProxyDroid requires a ROOTED device